# Inverse of a $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let us consider a $2 \times2$ cov matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2(x) & \rho \sigma(x)\sigma(y)\\
\rho \sigma(x)\sigma(y) & \sigma^2(y)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is its inverse? $$\frac{1}{\sigma^2(x)\sigma^2(y)-\rho^2 \sigma^2(x)\sigma^2(y)}\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2(y) & -\rho \sigma(x)\sigma(y)\\
-\rho \sigma(x)\sigma(y) & \sigma^2(x)
\end{bmatrix}$$? Can we simplify it?

Comment: Check your signs.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have just edited. Can we simplify the expression?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of the $2\times2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ is $$\frac1\Delta\begin{pmatrix}\ \ d&-b\\-c&\ \ a\end{pmatrix}$$ as you can check by direct product.

Comment: The expression I wrote is correct, then right? Can we simplify it, given that it is a covarisnce matrix?

Comment: @LearningProb: see for yourself, there is no real simplification possible. The formula is already simple.